Turn off arXiv information in revtex4-2
I want to remove the arXiv-info in a reference if it was published elsewhere. In a different discussion I found the option noeprint, but it seems to be ignored as demonstrated in this minimal example:
\documentclass[%
reprint,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps
pra,
noeprint
]{revtex4-2}

% Bibliographystyle
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}

\begin{document}
    
This is a test \cite{briegel2001}.

% BIBLIOGRAPHY
\bibliography{refs.bib}
\end{document}

bib-file:
@article{briegel2001,
  title = {Persistent Entanglement in Arrays of Interacting Particles},
  author = {Briegel, Hans J. and Raussendorf, Robert},
  year = {2001},
  month = jan,
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
  volume = {86},
  number = {5},
  eprint = {quant-ph/0004051},
  pages = {910--913},
  issn = {0031-9007, 1079-7114},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.86.910},
  urldate = {2021-07-29},
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  keywords = {Cluster States,Quantum Physics},
}


Change eprint into ORIeprint.

If you the remove the \bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}, the arXiv information is not shown for @article. The title is then shown by default (the new Physical Review standard), but this can be removed with nolongbibliography in the documentclass options. There will still be a title in arXiv references, with the default @misc entry exported by arXiv: I remove the title from arXiv entries along with unwanted primaryClass etc.
\documentclass[%
reprint,
amsmath,amssymb,
aps
pra,
noeprint,
nolongbibliography
]{revtex4-2}


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
  @article{briegel2001,
  title = {Persistent Entanglement in Arrays of Interacting Particles},
  author = {Briegel, Hans J. and Raussendorf, Robert},
  year = {2001},
  month = jan,
  journal = {Physical Review Letters},
  volume = {86},
  number = {5},
  eprint = {quant-ph/0004051},
  pages = {910--913},
  issn = {0031-9007, 1079-7114},
  doi = {10.1103/PhysRevLett.86.910},
  urldate = {2021-07-29}, 
  archiveprefix = {arXiv},
  keywords = {Cluster States,Quantum Physics}
} 

@misc{kaiwen2024,
      author={Kaiwen and Zhu and Zain Mehdi and Joseph J. Hope and Simon A. Haine},
      eprint={2408.17092},
      archivePrefix={arXiv},
      url={https://arxiv.org/abs/2408.17092}
}
\end{filecontents*}

%\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-2}
 

\begin{document}
    
This is a test \cite{briegel2001,kaiwen2024}.

\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}


